# Populate sibling cells on keyup event

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbctM/3/) for what I'm about to discuss.

I have three input boxes and I want to make them so that as the user types into any one of them, the others will populate with some text. It should be set so that if the user is typing in the first cell, the two cells to the right are populated, or if the user is typing in the last cell in the row, the first two cells are populated.

The code I have so far is in the Fiddle. I've tried `.next()` about a million times and I can't get it to work.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

JS:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).keyup(function() {
        var tmp = $(this).val();
        $(this).next('input').val("asdf");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Try http://knockoutjs.com, specifically see `ko.observables()`s. Also, there's *literally* no reason not to post that markup/code *in your question*.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mbctM/2/

Comment: Just keep in mind you need to be careful with you selectors and not use global ones when you mean to traverse those within a range. For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/mbctM/6/ adeneo's is probably cleaner, but that gives you the idea.

Comment: It works, but if I have another row (which I do), then those are updated as well. I just want the current row updated.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/mbctM/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).closest('td').siblings('td').find('input').val(this.value);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbctM/7/)

**EDIT:**

To exclude the first one:

```
$('input:gt(0)').on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).closest('td').siblings('td').not(':first').find('input').val(this.value);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbctM/9/)

Comment: This is perfect. I just realized that I actually have four columns, and I do NOT want the first one to update. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @JaredFarrish - oops, typo! Just used it to log something to the console !

Comment: @Jon - I'm guessing this is kind've a silly traversal, but `:first` is the psuedo selector you could use: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/mbctM/8/

Comment: Here's the actual code. I just tried to dumb it down for this post. http://jsfiddle.net/hcbzQ/ The idea is that it'll work like an excel spreadsheet where the user can type an expense in any field, and the surrounding ones (bi-weekly/monthly/annually) will calculate based off of the one they're typing in. So the bi-weekly one will always be the annual cell divided by 26. They should be able to type into any cell (bi-weekly, monthly, annually) and the others will update though. They can edit the first column, but they're just headers, so they shouldn't be updating at all.

Comment: Would I be better off just using a plugin? I just don't know of any where you can set the equations for the cells like I'm describing.

Comment: Nope, I think you are better of just figuring it out yourself, but it's a bit too much for me, with all the elements and different scripts, dynamic elements etc. But I'll take a wild guess and say you would have to delegate a lot of those handlers as some of the elements are inserted dyanmically.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like it. Thanks for all of your help, though!